# How to create one register in ember.js? store.createRecord

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

Hi I'm trying to create one data using emberjs + ember-data + rest adapter.

It works when the data is save, but in the template that i'm using it's possible that you redirect back for the list of **"groups"** in this case if you already pass in the route of group create, it generates one empty register into the store, i'd like to avoid that, but i'm not sure what i should put into the route to specify what is the model data that i'd be handling while attempt to insert.

The same scenario happens when in the controller after call **"save"** it retrieves one error in the API that i'm requesting it also make the insert at the database.

I've research a bit and I could not found anywhere something clear of how to create one record, and handle that in case of errors or in case that someone leaves the template view without trigger the action to persist the data.

**Router:**

```
App.GroupsCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @store.createRecord('group')

  renderTemplate: ->
    @render 'groups.create',
      outlet: 'content'
      into: 'application'
```

For that controller is render one view that has a form and in submit it calls the action save of controller:

**Template:**

```
<div class="container-content">
    <h1>Group</h1>
    {{#link-to 'groups' }}List Groups{{/link-to}}
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {{input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p>
        <button {{action save}}>Save</button>
    </p>
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
App.GroupsCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  needs: ['group']

  actions:
   "save": (data) ->
      group = @get('model')
      group.set('name', @get('name'))
      group.save().then =>
         @transitionToRoute 'groups'
```

**How is the right way to create one router + controller to create data in emberjs?**

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend invoking any store/data methods in the router, not the controller. To handle removing the data when leaving the route you need to implement the deactivate method on the route, which will be triggered when the user navigates from the route. In there, you need to delete the model:

```
AppGroupsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @store.createRecord 'group'
  deactivate: ->
    @get('currentModel').deleteRecord
```

If you don't want to show the model if it is not saved to the store, then you need to filter the displayed list by the 'isSaved' property on the model.

Comment: yeah, i have figure this out in IRC, thank you for the answer, it just not looks right to me, a bit strange such behavior, it should have somehow a way to create just a raw entity without push that to story, that would be push only after the save...